# GWT: Javascript implementation of JRE classes

Tags: compiler-construction, gwt

Sometimes I'd like to take a peek into the implementation of the JRE classes, which is used to generate the JavaScript code.

For some classes, I can find a corresponding implementation by guessing its name, e.g. `com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.StringBuilderImpl`. But where's the implementation for `java.util.Date` for example? Where do I find it, and how does GWT find it (via some configuration file?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where do I find it

A quick `find` on GWT trunk reveals [`user.super.com.google.gwt.emul.java.util.Date.java`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/Date.java) and [`user.super.com.google.gwt.emul.java.sql.Date.java`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/sql/Date.java). The `user.super.com.google.gwt.emul` package holds more emulated Java classes.

> how does GWT find it (via some configuration file?)

[The module XML file](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/Emulation.gwt.xml) has the `<super-source/>` directive which tells the compiler where to find the source, relative to the module root. I'm assuming here that no parameters means that the `user.super.com.google.gwt.emul` becomes the "root" and thus `user.super.com.google.gwt.emul.java.util.Date.java` becomes `java.util.Date.java` (notice for example that the package specified in that emulated Data.java is not `user.super.com.google.gwt.emul.java.util` but `java.util`).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The reason I didn't find it: Eclipse shows the packages under com.google.gwt.emul as empty (in gwt-user.jar)! However, when I unjar it, the package is filled with java sources - it's all there. I think I know, why Eclipse doesn't show them: The package statement doesn't match the path in the jar. But now I know where they are, thanks for your help!